# Wrong version of TensorFlow imported in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, python-import

I am trying to load TensorFlow 1.12 (I'm working with some legacy code) in a Jupyter notebook using a conda environment. Everything used to work fine, but now it seems that the wrong version of TensorFlow is being imported. I activated the conda environment (called `shared_env`) before launching the notebook server. I have the conda environment set up as a kernel for my notebook. When I check the installed version of TensorFlow by running `!conda list tensorflow` in the notebook, I see the following:

```
# packages in environment at /opt/anaconda3/envs/shared_env:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
tensorflow                1.12.0          gpu_py36he74679b_0  
tensorflow-base           1.12.0          gpu_py36had579c0_0  
tensorflow-gpu            1.12.0               h0d30ee6_0  
tensorflow-probability    0.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
```

However, when I run

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.__version__
```

the output is `2.6.2`. My conda environment is correctly listed in the PATH as `/opt/anaconda3/envs/shared_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages`, but there seems to be a different path that is accessed first, potentially causing the issue: `/home/USERNAME/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`.

Is there some way to force the notebook to load the version of TensorFlow from the conda environment and not whatever local version it sees first?

Comment: Would deleting all other versions from your system be an option for you? Even only for a temporarly test? From the info that you have provided some user settings overwrite your environment.

Comment: Good idea. Deleting the offending local version of TensorFlow seems to fix the issue. However, I'm still confused about what went wrong...

Comment: In fact, I seem to be having this problem with other packages as well, like `h5py`